# Magento fatal error in frondend and admin both?

Tags: magento-1.9

PHP Fatal error:

```
Class 'Eecom_CustomerGroupsPrice_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found in /html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234
```

Frontned and  Admin both are not working. How can I overcome this issue.

Comment: clear compilation and recompile it again.

Comment: I did not enable/disable the compilation, so how did this happen?

Comment: I believe compilation ran already, so only it's trying to get the file from `includes/src/` folder

Comment: Thanks @MeenakshiSundaramR, Now it is working fine. But How do we make sure this doesn't happen in the future?

Comment: Whenever you are going to add new module, disbale the compilation and recompile it.

Comment: But compilation was disabled, We didn,t touch it. then how can it possible

Answer (score 0):

Go to file include/config.php

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Comment oust as above code